# What factors decide when/why a status-planned tag is added?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, moderators, moderator-abilities

What criteria is used when applying the [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag? I've seen that **status-planned** is one of the restricted tags that can only be added or removed by a moderator (or employee). But, I can't find the specifics of how/when they decide to apply this tag for a particular bug or feature request.

Is there any particular rule or reason before this tag is applied/added?

The [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) info. [details page reads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-planned/info):

> Wheels are in motion, the sand falls through the hour glass and we're
>   looking down the barrel of something coming along sweet.
>
> We're in a world now of a promised feature, tweak or enhancement to
>   fruit.
>
> A change in functionality has been considered and received positively,
>   and work on it is either in progress, or will begin soon.

The answer on [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work) says:

> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
>
> Indicates that a feature request has been considered and received
>   positively enough that its implementation has been placed in the
>   development queue.

Both of the above points gives you only a generic/standard information.

There are few good feature requests and bugs reported on meta but they don't seem to get noticed enough even after having a fair amount of upvotes (assuming votes are considered as one of the factor).

I've also noticed that in a few cases the **status-planned** tag gets immediately applied (on the same day of posting) for some newly posted bugs/feature requests even though they have received very little votes. The only thing I can think of here is *how critical the bug/feature request is.

I guess "criticalness" also plays an important role in determining whether or not the tag should be applied. But, I believe there are few more factors out there.

It would be great if someone from the official side of the Stack Exchange team provided more details on the factors determining when the [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag is used.

Comment: Yes, it will take about [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514). Seriously tho, this tag simply means it's now on the todo, and what/how/why/when will vary from one task to another. You might be lucky and a staff member answers with some in-house info (not sure what they can tell you more than a usual todo list and working through it).

Comment: I only skim read, sorry if I misunderstood. I guess discussions in-house from staff putting forward ideas from questions here. Same as any company does. I'm not sure it's vote based, as I've seen feature requests with negative score end up with "status-completed" and FRs with 600+ score denied. I guess it's whatever they feel is worthwhile and a good idea for the sites

Comment: @James oops... you edited your comment and hence the overlap. Anyway, so its a classified in-house info. and can't be shared with community. But then "whatever they feel" seems kinda willy-nilly.... Don't they consider how would the community feel?

Comment: I was speculating/discussing the most logical/likely idea, hence comment not an answer :) Only Stack Staff can answer your with 100% accuracy. I'm sure someone will. They will certainly read and consider votes and community feedback, but votes/discussions on some Meta sites don't always reflect the needs of a greater community. Even considering how the users feel, and the sites being "community driven" it is also a business at the end of the day.

Comment: @random thanks for editing question. One question, shouldn't *how critical the bug/feature request in italic mode? or do you wanted that way?

Comment: No, you went overboard with the use of both italics and bold that both need to be removed as much as possible to make it sane

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the most part, [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) means we are actually actively doing stuff to make it happen. Much of the time, someone's literally working on writing the code, although sometimes we're nailing down a spec or defining edge cases.

It's usually reserved for things we're totally committed to.  So, since we don't run big backlogs in favor or prioritizing things right when we can get cranking on em, [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) usually means an actual human is doing actual stuff to make it happen.

We generally don't use it for ideas that sound smart and useful that we hope to do sometime in the future.

Comment: This answer is 1000 times better than the poetry in *About status-design  "Wheels are in motion, the sand falls through...."* Please replace it with this one.

Comment: To be clear, though, a *lack* of [status-planned] also doesn't necessarily mean nothing is happening. On the Q&A side of things we honestly almost never use this tag for anything at this point. It may not always remain this way, but I want to be careful about setting up expectations or lack thereof.

Comment: @AnnaLear Good point. Definitely helps and the community will surely understand.