# dead img-link on "The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta"

Tags: bug, blog, link-rot

On https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/ is a dead link to a picture in the section with the title

> Take Ownership of Your Community

below the term `Constitutional Convention`

Comment: Thanks for catching another one. My original request is marked as "status-planned" by Jon Chan. So it means the fix is on the way

Comment: 6-8 weeks and it (might be) fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard may be little longer... read the Jon Chan's comment on my post

Comment: @Hacker 6-8 months?

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M well u know sometimes things get haywire... I even posted a question about this [What factors decide when/why a status-planned tag is added?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260378/what-factors-decide-when-why-a-status-planned-tag-is-added) Some of the [status-planned] posts go way back to year 2011.